# Solving for a system of unknowns with Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have the following code to solve a system of 3 equations for 3 unknowns:

```
k = Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]
m = {{-Sqrt[pi/2]*i*(k1/(2*k))*Exp[-k*h], 
Exp[-k*h] + Sqrt[pi/2]*Kn*k*Exp[-k*h], 
0}, {-Sqrt[pi/2]*i*(k2/2*k)*Exp[-k*h], 0, 
Exp[-k*h] + 
 Sqrt[pi/2]*Kn*k*Exp[-k*h]}, {(1/2*Kn)*Exp[-k*r3] - (k/2*Kn)*r3*
  Exp[-k*r3] + (k/2*Kn)*h*Exp[-k*r3] + (k1^2/2*Kn*k)*r3*
  Exp[-k*r3] + (k2^2/2*Kn*k)*r3*Exp[-k*r3] - (k1^2/2*Kn*k)*h*
  Exp[-k*r3] + (k2^2/2*Kn*k)*h*Exp[-k*r3], -i*k1*Exp[-k*r3], -i*k2*
 Exp[-k*r3]}};
```

This creates the matrix on the left-hand side for the coefficients of `x,y,z` and on the right-hand side I create the vector of constant terms and try to solve.

```
 m.{x, y, z} == {i*(h/4*pi*Kn)*(k1/k)*Exp[-k*h] -  Sqrt[pi/2]*(h/2*pi)*i*k1*Exp[-k*h], 
   i*(h/4*pi*Kn)*(k2/k)*Exp[-k*h] - Sqrt[pi/2]*(h/2*pi)*i*k2*Exp[-k*h],0}
 Solve[%, {x, y, z}];
```

However, when I try to run this Mathematica seems unable to evaluate it (or at least it is taking a very long time).

Comment: In Mathematica yours `pi` is `Pi` with capital letter.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was trying Maple first.  With Maple I seem to get a solution instantly but the expression which it gives for A is very long so I am checking if I get the same with Mathematica.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the **Solve** command inhibits the output of the result.

Comment: In Mathematica the imaginary unit is `I` (not `ì`)

Comment: The semicolon is not in my original code for some reason, it just seems to run without ever generating a result.

Comment: Works for me in version 12.0, producing a big output.

Comment: Hmm yes, is it the first coefficient A which is the big output?  This is what I obtained in Maple as well.

Comment: This might help a bit with the output size. `linpolys = 
  m.{x, y, z} - {i*(h/4*pi*Kn)*(k1/k)*Exp[-k*h] - 
     Sqrt[pi/2]*(h/2*pi)*i*k1*Exp[-k*h], 
    i*(h/4*pi*Kn)*(k2/k)*Exp[-k*h] - 
     Sqrt[pi/2]*(h/2*pi)*i*k2*Exp[-k*h], 0};
{rhs, lhs} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[linpolys, {x, y, z}]];
soln = Simplify[LinearSolve[lhs, -rhs]];`

Comment: Is this just an algebraic simplification, or does it involve some approximations as I need this to be an exact solution.

Comment: Also my code is still not finished evaluating although I am using version 12.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

k = Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2];
```

`Simplify` as you go along

```
m = {{-Sqrt[Pi/2]*I*(k1/(2*k))*Exp[-k*h], 
     Exp[-k*h] + Sqrt[Pi/2]*Kn*k*Exp[-k*h], 0}, 
     {-Sqrt[Pi/2]*I*(k2/2*k)*Exp[-k*h], 0, 
      Exp[-k*h] + Sqrt[Pi/2]*Kn*k*Exp[-k*h]}, 
     {(1/2*Kn)*Exp[-k*r3] - (k/2*Kn)*r3*
       Exp[-k*r3] + (k/2*Kn)*h*Exp[-k*r3] + (k1^2/2*Kn*k)*r3*
       Exp[-k*r3] + (k2^2/2*Kn*k)*r3*Exp[-k*r3] - (k1^2/2*Kn*k)*h*
       Exp[-k*r3] + (k2^2/2*Kn*k)*h*Exp[-k*r3], -I*k1*Exp[-k*r3], 
       -I*k2*Exp[-k*r3]}} // FullSimplify;

eqn = m.{x, y, z} == {I*(h/4*Pi*Kn)*(k1/k)*Exp[-k*h] - 
      Sqrt[Pi/2]*(h/2*Pi)*I*k1*Exp[-k*h], 
     I*(h/4*Pi*Kn)*(k2/k)*Exp[-k*h] - Sqrt[Pi/2]*(h/2*Pi)*I*k2*Exp[-k*h], 0} //
    FullSimplify;

sol = Solve[eqn, {x, y, z}][[1]] // FullSimplify

(* {x -> (h (k1^2 + k2^2) π (-Kn + 
       Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Sqrt[2 π]))/((k2^4 + k1^2 (1 + k2^2)) Sqrt[
      2 π] - 
     h (-1 + k1^2 - k2^2) (k1^2 + k2^2) Kn (2 + 
        Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn Sqrt[2 π]) + 
     Kn (2 Sqrt[
         k1^2 + k2^2] + (k1^2 + k2^2) (2 (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) r3 + 
           Kn Sqrt[2 π] (1 + (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] r3)))), 
 y -> (I h k1 π (-Kn + 
       Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Sqrt[2 π]) (-k2^2 (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) Sqrt[
        2 π] + 
       h (-1 + k1^2 - k2^2) (k1^2 + k2^2) Kn (2 + 
          Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn Sqrt[2 π]) - 
       Kn (2 Sqrt[
           k1^2 + k2^2] + (k1^2 + k2^2) (2 (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) r3 + 
             Kn Sqrt[2 π] (1 + (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]
                  r3)))))/(2 Sqrt[
     k1^2 + k2^2] (2 + 
       Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn Sqrt[2 π]) ((k2^4 + k1^2 (1 + k2^2)) Sqrt[
        2 π] - 
       h (-1 + k1^2 - k2^2) (k1^2 + k2^2) Kn (2 + 
          Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn Sqrt[2 π]) + 
       Kn (2 Sqrt[
           k1^2 + k2^2] + (k1^2 + k2^2) (2 (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) r3 + 
             Kn Sqrt[2 π] (1 + (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]
                  r3))))), 
 z -> -((I h k2 π (-Kn + 
         Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Sqrt[2 π]) (2 Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn - 
         k1^2 (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) Sqrt[2 π] - 
         h (-1 + k1^2 - k2^2) (k1^2 + k2^2) Kn (2 + 
            Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn Sqrt[2 π]) + (k1^2 + 
            k2^2) Kn (2 (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) r3 + 
            Kn Sqrt[2 π] (1 + (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]
                 r3))))/(2 Sqrt[
       k1^2 + k2^2] (2 + 
         Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn Sqrt[2 π]) ((k2^4 + k1^2 (1 + k2^2)) Sqrt[
          2 π] - 
         h (-1 + k1^2 - k2^2) (k1^2 + k2^2) Kn (2 + 
            Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] Kn Sqrt[2 π]) + 
         Kn (2 Sqrt[
             k1^2 + k2^2] + (k1^2 + k2^2) (2 (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) r3 + 
               Kn Sqrt[2 π] (1 + (-1 + k1^2 + k2^2) Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]
                    r3))))))} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Version 12.0.0 for Mac OS X (macOS 10.15.2) on my laptop (MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014); 3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7; 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3) using `AbsoluteTiming`: defining `m` with `FullSimplify` takes `0.483898 sec`; `FullSimplify` for the equation takes `6.39681 sec`; solving the equation and `FullSimplify` the result takes `40.422 sec`; and verifying the solution with `Simplify` takes `0.129644 sec`. The `40.422 sec` is slow but not "forever".

Comment: I noticed as well that if I set the right-hand side to 0 by writing eqn = m.{x, y, z} == {0, 0, 0} // FullSimplify; that it gives the solution as x=0, y=0,z=0, this can't be right?

Comment: Evaluate `m.{x, y, z} /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}` and you will get `{0, 0, 0}`